# JUnit test method, testing a feature of a add method

Tags: java, testing, methods, junit

Suppose that the add method of MyList takes one argument, and is specified to throw a
NullPointerException if null is given as its argument. Complete this JUnit test method to test that feature of
the add method:

```
    public void testAddNull() {
    MyList<String> ls = new MyList<String>();

    }
```

this is the answer:

```
    public void testAddNull() {
    MyList<String> ls = new MyList<String>();
      try {
        ls.add(null);
        fail();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
      }
    }
```

why exactly is fail(); needed here, wouldn't the ls.add(null) cause it to fail, so isn't putting fail(); here redundant?

Comment: You should take fail() off...

Comment: that's whats written in the answer key, if i take it off will it function the same?

Comment: I don't know, but you should try and find out. It is the quickest way of answering your question, but I don't have Java compiler at hand right now.

Answer (score 4):

The above test method will fail, if the `ls.add(null);` does *not* throw a `NullPointerException`. Since the desired behavior is to throw an exception, the test will pass when the exception is catched at `catch (NullPointerException e)`.

With Junit 4 You could also do this:

```
@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void testAddNull() {
    ls.add(null);
}
```

which would require the tested code to throw a `NullPointerException`. Otherwise, the test would fail.